# Can you programmatically detect a change in MPMoviePlayerController currentPlaybackTime

Tags: ios, xcode, core-animation, mpmovieplayercontroller, calayer

I've written custom control which allows the user to change the `currentPlaybackTime` of a `MPMoviePlayerController` by clicking or dragging on a custom `UIButton` that displays an image of some musical notation. The code uses the x position of the touch event to update `currentPlaybackTime` and it all works fine. I also have a `CALayer` (a vertical red line) that shows the user where they have touched on the control.

What I'd like to do now is have the red line's (CALayer object) position update if the user changes the `currentPlaybackTime` property of the movie player using the scrubber (slider) control.

Obviously `currentPlaybackTime` is always updating as the movie plays, but is there a way to detect if the user interferes with this by skipping forward or backwards?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Key-Value-Observing to track changes of `currentPlaybackTime` in your `MPMoviePlayerController`, but that might generate a lot of events and thus negatively affect your performance. Maybe you can also use KVO with the `playbackState` property of your `MPMoviePlayerController`, I believe it changes when the user starts seeking.

Another alternative is that you just setup a repeating timer that updates quite frequently, and everytime it fires you check the new value of `currentPlaybackTime`. But that might look choppy and it could also affect performance.

Comment: Yes, playbackState was the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: currentPlaybackTime is not KVO-compliant.

Comment: KMP is correct, you can't use KVO to observe currentPlaybackTime